# Get a count of criteria & criteria from filter option in excel

Tags: vba, excel

How to count & get a list of values from auto filter criteria in Excel? After applying a filter option for a column "A" you will find criteria with check box, I want to get the count of criteria & the criteria as well. How can I do that with VBA code? thanks :)

Comment: I think this **could** be a good question.........please update your post with a **specific** example of the information you want to retrieve.

Comment: Sounds specific enough to me.  Thanks for asking the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub MatchCount()
Dim Criteria(1 To n, 1 To 2)                                             'Define 2 dimensional array to store criteria and its count, change n as per your requirements
Dim i, j, k As Integer
For k = 1 To n
    Criteria(k, 2) = 0
Next k
 i = 1
 Index = 1
Do While ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) <> 0
    For j = 1 To n
        If Criteria(j, 1) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) Then                    'Counts the criteria
            Criteria(j, 2) = Criteria(j, 2) + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    If j = n+1 Then                                                          'Stores the criteria If it is not found in the array and sets count to one
        Criteria(Index, 1) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1)
        Criteria(Index, 2) = Criteria(Index, 2) + 1
        Index = Index + 1
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
For i = 1 To n                                                           'Print criteria and their respective counts
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3) = Criteria(i, 1)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4) = Criteria(i, 2)
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this as a half-answer as it contains some code, a link and a 'throw my hands up in the air - it's going to take ages to figure it all out'.

First the link which made me stop (as I haven't got time):
http://yoursumbuddy.com/autofilter-vba-operator-parameters/

Now the code that I've written so far.  The idea is that you enter the formula `=Filter_Criteria()` in the cell above each column in your table and it would list the criteria selected for that column.  I stopped when I realised that the operators are a hell of a lot more complicated than 2003 (How would you list filter by colour for starters)

```
Public Function Filter_Criteria() As String

    Dim rMe As Range

    If TypeName(Application.Caller) = "Range" Then

        'Where's the function being called from.
        Set rMe = Application.Caller

        'Is Autofilter on?
        If rMe.Parent.AutoFilterMode Then
            With rMe.Parent.AutoFilter

                'Does the function sit a row above the filtered range?
                If Not Intersect(rMe.Offset(1), .Range) Is Nothing Then

                    With .Filters(rMe.Column - .Range.Column + 1)
                        If .On Then

                            'Action depending on type of operator.
                            Select Case .Operator

                                'Specific values selected.
                                Case xlFilterValues


                                'Date Filter
                                Case 0

                                'Selected 'Last Month' in date range.
                                Case xlFilterDynamic

                            End Select
                        End If
                    End With
                End If
            End With
        End If

    End If

End Function
```

Hopefully this code and the link will give you a good starting point.... let us know if you reach the end.